# Visual Studio Extension : Changing the visible text of collapsed blocks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing a Visual Studio Extension to customize my editor. I would like to change the text that is displayed when a block of code is collapsed.

I have tried the following code :

```
ITagAggregator<IntraTextAdornmentTag> aggregator;
[...]
aggregator.BatchedTagsChanged += OnBatchedTagsChanged;
[...]
public void OnBatchedTagsChanged(object sender, BatchedTagsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string newText;
    bool textCreated;
    NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection list = new NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection(e.Spans.SelectMany(x => x.GetSpans(textView.TextBuffer)));
    if (list.Count != 0)
    {
        IEnumerable<IMappingTagSpan<IntraTextAdornmentTag>> tags = aggregator.GetTags(list);
        foreach (IMappingTagSpan<IntraTextAdornmentTag> tag in tags)
        {
            if (tag.Tag.Adornment is OutliningCollapsedAdornmentControl)
            {
                NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans = tag.Span.GetSpans(textView.TextSnapshot);
                if (spans.Count == 0) continue;
                OutliningCollapsedAdornmentControl adornmentControl = (OutliningCollapsedAdornmentControl)tag.Tag.Adornment;
                TextBlock textBlock = adornmentControl.GetChild<TextBlock>();
                textCreated = TryCreateText(spans[0], out newText);
                if (textCreated)
                {
                    adornmentControl.Content = newText;
                    textBlock.Text = newText;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I does change the text, but when it's scrolled out of the the screen and back in, the text reverts back to the default value.

---

**Edit :**

I also tried [MSDN's walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee197665.aspx).

I works fine if I collapse blocks by clicking on the "+" sign, but the blocks don't collapse when I use Ctrl+M+O.

I guess the problem comes from the fact that I'm creating regions that already exist.

---

Could someone please tell me what I could do?

(Tested both in VS2010 and VS2013 with the same result)

Comment: Which language is this for? Editing the adornment in such a way as you're doing now isn't really supported.

Comment: This is for C#. 
It's the first time I try to develop an extension. I wrote this based on the source code of a few extensions I found, but since none of them did what I'm trying to do, I sort of improvised... Could you help me get back on track?

Comment: In general, what you're trying to do is unsupported, sorry. There are many things the extensibility model doesn't expect people to do, and this is one of them.